# Get the upcoming CSS transition properties

Tags: css, reactjs, events, properties, transition

I'm building an interface with React, and I'd like to get the properties of div container (clientWidth and clientHeight) after I changed a class.

The main problem is that there is a CSS transition of 0.2s for the width/height properties, so whenever I try to detect a (future) DOM modification thanks to React (with componentDidMount) or with a MutationObserver, I'm getting the clientWidth and clientHeight right before the transition starts.

Ideally, I'd like to get the properties that are about to be applied after the transition so I could re-render sub-components and give them the future width/height they need.

Is there any good way to do this? 
I thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a trigger for css transition end: https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback

So you can wait with the height and width detection till this event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks Martin P. ! 
But this is not the miraculous solution I've been dreaming for :D

This is indeed a good solution to detect the end of a transition, but I want to know if there was any possibility to know BEFORE the transition starts (in my case) the client width/height in px  of the element that are going to be effective.
I doubt that any solution currently exist but who knows, I tried my chance in this topic.

But I still appreciate your solution, it might be useful for near-similar problems! :)

Comment: Okay, now i do understand. This is what you are searching for:

document.getElementById("yourId").getBoundingClientRect().height;

Comment: Sorry, you're still missing it @martin-p :D
Ik how to get an element dimensions (**clientWidth/clientHeight** i.e.)

What I wanted to get are the _future_ width and height that are going to be effective **after that the transition starts and ends**
Here's how I'd sum it up :


**class event detected** --> **transition detected** --> _future properties computed, and able to obtain in order to propagate it in React_ --> **transition starts** --> **children rendering starts kind of synchronously with the correct 'future' properties** --> **transition ends ; children rendering ends**

Comment: But as I said, i didn't find any satisfying solution on the web, and it seems like there is no one, so I just tried my chance on this topic to see if a miracle occurs among the answers :p
Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Ah :D I am sooo sorry! My command of english isn't so good, but i try to improve it. So replace the .getBoundingClientRect().height; by .scrollHeight - this will solve your problem!! Please don't tell me i am wrong, again :D

Comment: Still not :D
It will give back the height **before the transition** , as .clientHeight (which are the same if the whole of the element is visible).
I do think that no native properties of a DOM element can actually give the informations i mentioned  :(

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand what exactly is the problem if you provide a code example? I can not imagine, that it isn't possible.

Comment: I truly believe that the best way to explain what I want to obtain was the kind of path I wrote 4 comments ago :|

I actually chose to give up some design functionalities because of the implementation difficulties and my personal dev time constraints.

If you're interesting in this issue, feel free to work on it, but I threw this question like a bottle in the sea, hoping for any miraculous solution to this problem that everyone seem to struggle with.